# How to get rid of decimal point in number in a JSON String in Android which is converted to HashMap by GSON?

Tags: android, json, listview, gson, decimal-point

I get a JSON from a web service. I parse it and put the objects in my
 ArrayList< HashMap < String, String > > . I fill out a ListView using this ArrayList. 
My problem is that some numbers in the original JSON do not have decimal point. But at the end they are shown with decimal point. And some times even worse! They are displayed in scientific format sometimes :(

(I use GSON. After the usage of GSON to convert JSONs to HashMap, the decimal points appear)

Here is the way numbers are shown. I want them NOT to contain any decimal point.

[image]

Here is the part of the code for my adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("PropertyListings");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map = (HashMap<String, String>) new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.getString(i), map.getClass());
            listOfProperties.add(map);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(mContext , listOfProperties, 
                                                R.layout.list_view_items, 
                                                new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_CODE, TAG_NUMBER_OF_ROOMS,TAG_PPRICE_PER_UNIT_AREA,TAG_CREATION_DATE}, 
                                                new int[] {R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtTitle,R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody1, R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody2,R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody3,R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody4});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

TextViews in my ListViewItems look like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSearchResultTxtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

If there is any part of the code needed please mention. I will add it right away.

Comment: I don't get what u mean. Where?

Comment: I suppose you are mistaken. There is no data type defined here. String JSON goes to ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: use substring and trim the rest

Comment: Im looking for more straight forward answers. Im not willing to manipulate the data. Get it out from JSON... trim... send it back to adapter... Im sure there is a better solution. I suppose the answer lies in the way of my dealing with ArrayList and ListViews.

Comment: were you able to do this? Please post your answer so that others like me can learn.

Comment: @Mathew I solved it. But unfortunately I don't remember how. A looong time has passed. I will do my best to find my old codes and post the answer.

Comment: @Tina . Thanks for coming back. I was using json table to display the results. Added a Math.round inside the javascript.